# Exporting GridView to Microsoft Word html

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I am exporting a gridview to a word document via:

```
Response.Clear()
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Questionnaires.doc")
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-word"
Dim sw As New System.IO.StringWriter()
Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)


gridview1.RenderControl(hw)
Response.Write(sw.ToString())
Response.End()
```

But as microsoft renders the HTML differently, and is showing borders as it reads it as a table.. even when getting rid of the gridview borders and/or even making them white (worth a try) they still show up

any help is much appreciated

Comment: Hi Lanes, is the gridview a datagridview? More to the point, have you got some sort of table structure, if so you could create the table direct using the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` reference. Some ideas are [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w1702h4a.aspx). You can then directly edit the conditions i.e table size / columns as well as borders and colours. Hth Chicken

Comment: @Chicken : The OP appears to be using ASP.NET, so he's probably talking about a [**`System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview(v=vs.110).aspx). The basic principles are pretty much the same compared to the `System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView`.

Comment: Thank you guys for your replies, that is correct i am using an asp gridview, but without having to change the code behind to create the table is there not a way to get rid of the border lines?

Comment: Hi Lanes, unfortunately I dont think it will be possible without coding it. You're basically sending the information data to word and word is interpreting this is a table and then drawing your borders as a 'default'. I'm sorry I know very little about asp, but I hope you manage to get it working!